# Is Android's Dalvik SMP safe?

Tags: android

I am wondering if Android and Dalvik is SMP safe? For example how stable is gingerbread on multi-core CPU? When writing applications in Android do we worry about making it SMP safe?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/smp.html

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588076/is-dalviks-memory-model-the-same-as-javas/4610859#4610859

Answer (score 0):

Be worry about thread safe.. The rest is managed by what is under dalvik : Linux
Linux kernel on multi core/socket architecture is SMP safe... then android as well.
Linux is used as an hardware abstraction layer to avoid that android app be worried about hardware singularities.. 
see end of web page "Linux Kernel" Section at http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html

[image: android stack]