# Is it a good idea to share thread-pool for different component use

Tags: android, multithreading

Let us have some background information , if you are using some library is releate to network connection , database operation etc , you will need to run it on another thread instead of main thread .

Reference to Picasso :

```
 public Builder executor(ExecutorService executorService)
```

we can see they have expose the executorService for us .

as [here](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/index.html) for android developer doc say that it is better to run the tasks on thread pool.

so , is it the best solution of us to avoid create so many threads?? i think it is great . i think is time to stop use all of the new Thread(new Runnable(){}).start();

Answer (score 0):

Use an Executor. [Android concurrency usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646300/android-concurrency-usage)

**(edit)**

Best advice I can offer is, it depends on the granularity with which you need to control the tasks being executed.  Think about whether certain components may generate more tasks than others--which ones might be greedy.  Greedy components might warrant their own thread[pool].  For ui tasks, you already have the AsyncTask threadpool.

Comment: nice post , but i just want to discuss with expose a executor to share thread-pool corss different component, thanks

Comment: More a [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) question, because it's really designers choice on that one.

Comment: can you share more details??