# Is this way of passing objects between threads safe under JMM?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, java-memory-model

I'm looking for a safe way to pass an object from a background thread to the UI thread. Does the code below do it safely?

```
// on background thread
final HugeObject object = constructHugeObjectFromDatabaseAndNetwork();
uiThreadHandler.post(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() { doSomethingWithObject(object); }
});
```

I.e., do JMM rules allow the object to be in fact partially constructed during the doSomethingWithObject call? Also, how relevant JMM is for Android and its virtual machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - handlers are there to do exactly that: exchange information across threads in a thread safe way.

In practice, [handlers](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/9a7debe5857ffc7c71cfc4082b1b6d72a5cf81cd/core/java/android/os/Handler.java) use a [thread safe (synchronized) message queue](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/9a7debe5857ffc7c71cfc4082b1b6d72a5cf81cd/core/java/android/os/MessageQueue.java) to post messages, creating a happens-before relationship between your code and whatever will happen on the UI with your object.

[Recent versions of android comply with the JMM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588076/is-dalviks-memory-model-the-same-as-javas).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the implementation of `post()`. There's no memory barrier in the quoted code, so it generally wouldn't be thread safe. But, in practice, it becomes very difficult to have one thread waiting for a task to run without using a barrier to exchange objects. That is likely to be the case here, and if so, it will be safe.